# Memory Error - *** glibc detected *** php: double free or corruption (out): 0x0000000002818040

Tags: php, c++, laravel

Today I have encountered Error while running

```
php artisan migrate:refresh --seed
```

Error after Migration & Seeding

```
*** glibc detected *** php: double free or corruption (out): 0x0000000001de6040 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x75dee)[0x7f74dde92dee]
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x78c80)[0x7f74dde95c80]
/opt/alt/openssl/lib64/libcrypto.so.10(CRYPTO_free+0x1d)[0x7f74e04fa07d]
/opt/alt/openssl/lib64/libcrypto.so.10(sk_pop_free+0x30)[0x7f74e05a05b0]
/opt/alt/curlssl/usr/lib64/libcurl.so.4(+0x618c2)[0x7f74dfffe8c2]
/opt/alt/curlssl/usr/lib64/libcurl.so.4(curl_global_cleanup+0x55)[0x7f74dffce3d5]
php[0x5343d8]
php[0x691d15]
php[0x68b93c]
php(zend_hash_graceful_reverse_destroy+0xff)[0x6996cf]
php[0x68b6e6]
php(php_module_shutdown+0x2a)[0x62c65a]
php[0x723785]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xfd)[0x7f74dde3bd1d]
php[0x42dc75]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-008ad000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 26089499                           /opt/alt/php70/usr/bin/php
00aad000-00b49000 rw-p 004ad000 08:01 26089499                           /opt/alt/php70/usr/bin/php
00b49000-00b65000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
01d0f000-01f56000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7f74cc000000-7f74cc021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f74cc021000-7f74d0000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f74d3adf000-7f74d4200000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f74d48e2000-7f74d48ef000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 6556567                    /lib64/libnss_files-2.12.so
7f74d48ef000-7f74d4aee000 ---p 0000d000 08:01 6556567                    /lib64/libnss_files-2.12.so
7f74d4aee000-7f74d4aef000 r--p 0000c000 08:01 6556567                    /lib64/libnss_files-2.12.so
7f74d4aef000-7f74d4af0000 rw-p 0000d000 08:01 6556567                    /lib64/libnss_files-2.12.so
7f74dabc4000-7f74dabfd000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 26092074                   /opt/alt/php70/usr/lib64/php/modules/xdebug.so
7f74dabfd000-7f74dadfc000 ---p 00039000 08:01 26092074                   /opt/alt/php70/usr/lib64/php/modules/xdebug.so
7f74dadfc000-7f74dadff000 rw-p 00038000 08:01 26092074                   /opt/alt/php70/usr/lib64/php/modules/xdebug.so
7f74dadff000-7f74db000000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f74db01c000-7f74db039000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 6553688                    /lib64/libselinux.so.1
7f74db039000-7f74db238000 ---p 0001d000 08:01 6553688                    /lib64/libselinux.so.1
7f74db238000-7f74db239000 r--p 0001c000 08:01 6553688                    /lib64/libselinux.so.1
7f74db239000-7f74db23a000 rw-p 0001d000 08:01 6553688                    /lib64/libselinux.so.1
7f74db23a000-7f74db23b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f74db23b000-7f74db254000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 5375117                    /usr/lib64/libsasl2.so.2.0.23
7f74db254000-7f74db453000 ---p 00019000 08:01 5375117                    /usr/lib64/libsasl2.so.2.0.23
7f74db453000-7f74db454000 r--p 00018000 08:01 5375117                    /usr/lib64/libsasl2.so.2.0.23
7f74db454000-7f74db455000 rw-p 00019000 08:01 5375117                    /usr/lib64/libsasl2.so.2.0.23
7f74db455000-7f74db48e000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 6555551                    /lib64/libnspr4.so
7f74db48e000-7f74db68e000 ---p 00039000 08:01 6555551                    /lib64/libnspr4.so
7f74db68e000-7f74db68f000 r--p 00039000 08:01 6555551                    /lib64/libnspr4.so
7f74db68f000-7f74db691000 rw-p 0003a000 08:01 6555551                    /lib64/libnspr4.so
7f74db691000-7f74db693000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f74db693000-7f74db697000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 6555552                    /lib64/libplc4.so
7f74db697000-7f74db896000 ---p 00004000 08:01 6555552                    /lib64/libplc4.so
7f74db896000-7f74db897000 r--p 00003000 08:01 6555552                    /lib64/libplc4.so
7f74db897000-7f74db898000 rw-p 00004000 08:01 6555552                    /lib64/libplc4.so
7f74db898000-7f74db89b000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 6555553                    /lib64/libplds4.so
7f74db89b000-7f74dba9a000 ---p 00003000 08:01 6555553                    /lib64/libplds4.so
7f74dba9a000-7f74dba9b000 r--p 00002000 08:01 6555553                    /lib64/libplds4.so
7f74dba9b000-7f74dba9c000 rw-p 00003000 08:01 6555553                    /lib64/libplds4.so
7f74dba9c000-7f74dbac1000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 5374655                    /usr/lib64/libnssutil3.so
7f74dbac1000-7f74dbcc1000 ---p 00025000 08:01 5374655                    /usr/lib64/libnssutil3.so
7f74dbcc1000-7f74dbcc7000 r--p 00025000 08:01 5374655                    /usr/lib64/libnssutil3.so
7f74dbcc7000-7f74dbcc8000 rw-p 0002b000 08:01 5374655                    /usr/lib64/libnssutil3.so
7f74dbcc8000-7f74dbdfe000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 5378097                    /usr/lib64/libnss3.so
7f74dbdfe000-7f74dbffe000 ---p 00136000 08:01 5378097                    /usr/lib64/libnss3.so
7f74dbffe000-7f74dc003000 r--p 00136000 08:01 5378097                    /usr/lib64/libnss3.so
7f74dc003000-7f74dc005000 rw-p 0013b000 08:01 5378097                    /usr/lib64/libnss3.so
7f74dc005000-7f74dc007000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f74dc007000-7f74dc02f000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 5378099                    /usr/lib64/libsmime3.so
7f74dc02f000-7f74dc22e000 ---p 00028000 08:01 5378099                    /usr/lib64/libsmime3.so
7f74dc22e000-7f74dc232000 r--p 00027000 08:01 5378099                    /usr/lib64/libsmime3.so
7f74dc232000-7f74dc233000 rw-p 0002b000 08:01 5378099                    /usr/lib64/libsmime3.so
7f74dc233000-7f74dc26d000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 5378100                    /usr/lib64/libssl3.so
7f74dc26d000-7f74dc46d000 ---p 0003a000 08:01 5378100                    /usr/lib64/libssl3.so
7f74dc46d000-7f74dc470000 r--p 0003a000 08:01 5378100                    /usr/lib64/libssl3.so
7f74dc470000-7f74dc471000 rw-p 0003d000 08:01 5378100                    /usr/lib64/libssl3.so
7f74dc471000-7f74dc472000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f74dc472000-7f74dc480000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 6553781                    /lib64/liblber-2.4.so.2.5.6
7f74dc480000-7f74dc67f000 ---p 0000e000 08:01 6553781                    /lib64/liblber-2.4.so.2.5.6
7f74dc67f000-7f74dc680000 r--p 0000d000 08:01 6553781                    /lib64/liblber-2.4.so.2.5.6
7f74dc680000-7f74dc681000 rw-p 0000e000 08:01 6553781                    /lib64/liblber-2.4.so.2.5.6
7f74dc681000-7f74dc683000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 6553804                    /lib64/libkeyutils.so.1.3
7f74dc683000-7f74dc882000 ---p 00002000 08:01 6553804                    /lib64/libkeyutils.so.1.3
7f74dc882000-7f74dc883000 r--p 00001000 08:01 6553804                    /lib64/libkeyutils.so.1.3Aborted
```

Migrations & Seeding are successful, but why this error is coming..?

For now I know this is about Memory. I also saw questions about this here [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17343832/glibc-detected-double-free-or-corruption), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4063583/glibc-detected-double-free-or-corruption-message), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8786730/glibc-detected-double-free-or-corruption), but all of them are related with C++. If I need to solve this problem how can I solve. I am Hosting Laravel Project on Shared Hosting.

**UPDATE: ERROR RESOLVED**

I have contacted Hosting Provider to Solve this Error.
For me, they enabled `mysqlnd` Extension in PHP, But Solution may vary depending on Server PHP Configuration.

Comment: Why has this got two down-votes? Looks like a very valid question to me!

Comment: Down Voters.. Please comment why you are down-voting..?

Comment: I'm getting this on my server too, no idea why. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: @mikey242 Check Updated Question

Comment: @ZaheerAttar Great I'll get in touch with my hosting provider and ask them to test that out. Thanks for getting in touch with the solution.